# How to extract the text from the parent node excluding the text from the child node using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm trying to get text of a div, without getting text of the child span, here is my html :

```
  <div class="Travel">
  
    <!--ko text: marketName-->Résultat<!--/ko-->

    <span class="label">Cities</span>

  </div>
```

I want to get `Résultat`, Instead I get `Résultat Cities`

here is what I tried :

```
//div[@class='Travel']//text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Python use this -**

Direct Div text -

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="Travel"]').text()`

Div text through span tag -

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Cities"])/parent::div').text()`

**For Java use this -**

Direct Div text -

`driver.findElements(By.xpath('//div[@class="Travel"]')).getText();`

Div text through span tag -

`driver.findElements(By.xpath('//span[text()="Cities"])/parent::div')).getText();`

Answer (score 1):

The text `Résultat` is within a text node. So extract the text you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java), [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and `childNodes`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Travel']"))).toString());
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python), [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.Travel").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[2])
  ```